# Using Identity and Access Management with Java

Tags: java, identity, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, claims

I am working with Java application and i want to implement Single Sign on and Federation 
in my Java Application. I want to implement Claims Aware application in Java.How to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various Identity Provider for implementing single sign on:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations